# Textfield text clicking sound from keyboard is not getting in audio/video playing app flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on one video and audio player application that i have to record video and play the preview and upload that video with description of that video.

during writing description I am unable to get keyboard typing sound in ios devices

I am using textfield widget for write description

before typing i am pausing the video.

i am using [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) for playing video in application.

i have tried a lot to find the solution.

my life is got silent without that keyboard tapping sound.please help me to get the sound back :)

Comment: You can try using `SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click)` or try using Feedback class https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Feedback-class.html